# How to modify hopping strength of electron on a lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Let's suppose we have an electron hopping around on a lattice; for the simplest case you can take for example a 1D chain of Hydrogen atoms, described by the Hubbard model (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubbard_model). So the Hamiltonian has a term for interaction between an electron and an atom when the electron is localized at that atom, and a tunneling (or hopping) term $t$ allowing movement between sites.

My question is, in these sorts of lattice models with tunneling between neighbors, is it possible to change the hopping coefficient $t$ (by applying an external field, or temperature affects, etc) and how might we do that, or is it typically an intrinsic property of the lattice structure and composition which cannot be modified. Are there any examples of experiments where we change the hopping strength?

Comment: Polymers with different substitutions (Cl for F)?

Comment: @JonCuster I would like to know if it could be varied continuously.